# How can I get the "swipe down" icon from control center - iOS 7

Tags: icon, copyright, ios, applications

I would like to use the swipe down icon:

[image: Swipe down icon]

from Control Center of iOS 7 :

[image: Control center iOS 7]

in my iOS 7 app to indicate that you can swipe down this pop up :

[image: Pop up to swipe Twigit]

How can I get this icon. Am I allowed to use this icon anyway (I do iOS app)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's merely a downward facing chevron (which Apple can not trademark). Couldn't you simply draw it?

Answer (score 2):

I would think twice about using exact Apple icons in your own projects (especially if they are commercial projects), but that said, you can download an iOS7 PSD template from Teehan + Lax that contains the icon you need. They've been sharing these files for a few years now and they're very handy  (and pixel-perfect).

http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/